# bootstrap-4.0-dist gives error message,match jdk1.6 with myeclipse 10

Tags: java-6, myeclipse, statistics-bootstrap

I put the bootstrap-4.0-dist folder to the new web project folder of webroot,then I run the server and the console appear some errors and the bootstrap.bundle.js appeaared a big red "X",I copy the error message.

> bootstrap.bundle.js error message 1
>        Internal validation error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CaseStatement.resolveCase(CaseStatement.java:82) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.SwitchStatement.resolve(SwitchStatement.java:156) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.ja
>        va:338) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:
>        137) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:
>        292) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:
>        363) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.ja
>        va:344) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:
>        137) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:
>        292) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:
>        363) at org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.FunctionExpression.resolveType(FunctionExpression.java:57) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:279) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:477) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:394) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:612) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:305) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.compile(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:307) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.AbstractImageBuilder.compile(AbstractImageBuilder.java:232) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.IncrementalImageBuilder.build(IncrementalImageBuilder.java:135) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.buildDeltas(JavaBuilder.java:302) at 
>        org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:214) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:239) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:292) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:295) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:351) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:374) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241) at 
>        org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

**bootstrap.bundle.js error message 2**

The default case is already defined

This new web project is a empty project,named bootstrap201805.It's not congigured such as ssh and struts.But the error make me confuse.

```
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
信息: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Myeclipse\Common\binary\com.sun.java.jdk.win32.x86_1.6.0.013\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
信息: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
信息: Initialization processed in 538 ms
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
信息: Starting service Catalina
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
信息: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.35
2018-5-5 15:57:02 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
信息: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
2018-5-5 15:57:03 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
信息: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
2018-5-5 15:57:03 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory bootstrap20180120
2018-5-5 15:57:04 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:13 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory bootstrap20180120.myeclipse.bak
2018-5-5 15:57:14 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
严重: Exception starting filter struts2
Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:839)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:69)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:213)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:198)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:175)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
    ... 34 more
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Error filterStart
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Context [/bootstrap20180120.myeclipse.bak] startup failed due to previous errors
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201801.myeclipse.bak] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201801.myeclipse.bak] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201801.myeclipse.bak] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@970846]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:23 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory bootstrap201803try
2018-5-5 15:57:24 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
严重: Exception starting filter struts2
Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:839)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:69)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:213)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:198)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:175)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
    ... 34 more
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Error filterStart
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Context [/bootstrap201803] startup failed due to previous errors
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:32 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@f5d2fd]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory bootstrap201803.myeclipse.bak
2018-5-5 15:57:34 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:42 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
严重: Exception starting filter struts2
Caught exception while loading file struts-default.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:839)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:131)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reload(DefaultConfiguration.java:130)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:452)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.newDocumentBuilder(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.<init>(SAX2DOM.java:69)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:392)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.setResult(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:137)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.setup(DomHelper.java:213)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:198)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper$DOMBuilder.<init>(DomHelper.java:175)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:830)
    ... 34 more
2018-5-5 15:57:42 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Error filterStart
2018-5-5 15:57:43 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
严重: Context [/bootstrap201803.myeclipse.bak] startup failed due to previous errors
2018-5-5 15:57:43 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2018-5-5 15:57:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803.myeclipse.bak] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
2018-5-5 15:57:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803.myeclipse.bak] appears to have started a thread named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:43 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
严重: The web application [/bootstrap201803.myeclipse.bak] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1] (value [com.sun.faces.util.Util$1@d5c83f]) and a value of type [java.util.HashMap] (value [{com.sun.faces.patternCache={ = }}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
2018-5-5 15:57:44 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory bootstrap20180504
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory docs
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory examples
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
信息: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory ROOT
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
信息: Deploying web application directory xianProject
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
信息: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\xianProject\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2018-5-5 15:58:00 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
信息: validateJarFile(C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps\xianProject\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
2018-5-5 15:58:01 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
信息: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2018-5-5 15:58:01 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
信息: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
2018-5-5 15:58:01 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
信息: Jk running ID=0 time=0/40  config=null
2018-5-5 15:58:01 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
信息: Server startup in 58799 ms
```

Comment: Which "console" is the error appearing in? There are eclipse classes in the stack trace, which there shouldn't be if this is the server console.

Answer (score 0):

A part of problem is solved by searching.I delete other projects in the webapps folder.The details is following.
Tomcat6.o\webapps\
So the third problem is ok.The other problems about bootstrap is still bad.
Thank you very much.

My english is not bad and not good.I wondered if I understood your question right.I was not sure.I took some time to think about my answer.
I found the 2 problems of bootstrap.bundle.js not to influence the project running. So there is not any error message in the server console .You are right.Thanks!